# PHPBB3 - Get row from insert statement

Tags: php, sql, mysql, phpbb, phpbb3

When using `$db->sql_query` in PHPBB3, how would I get the id of a row created with an `insert` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Reference:

- [LAST_INSERT_ID vai phpbbdoctor.com](http://www.phpbbdoctor.com/blog/2008/08/29/building-a-better-board-banner-system-part-ii-using-last_insert_id/)
- [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Answer (score 2):

in phpBB3 you get an even better way, the dbal go a function for this: **$db->sql_nextid()**:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . USERS_TABLE . ' ' . $db->sql_build_array('INSERT', $user_ary);
$db->sql_query($sql);

$user_id = $db->sql_nextid();
```